# Show that the linear transformation is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Hi im having trouble with this homework question

"Let $F$ be a field.

Let $A ∈ M_{n×n}(F)$ be an invertible matrix. Show that the linear transformation
$L_A : F^
n → F^
n
, x→ Ax,$ is an isomorphism."

So since I need to show it's an isomorphism I need to show it's a linear transformation (which is is) along with injectivity and surjectivity. I have shown injectivity quite easily but I'm not sure how to show surjectivity.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: *Hint:* Have you used the assumption that $A$ is inventively?

Comment: I was going to set an equation up like $Ax=y$ then pre-multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ which leaves $x=A^{-1}y$. Would this be along the right lines?

Comment: Yes, that's all you need.

Comment: @HansHüttel "inventively" :-)

Comment: Autocorrect is the devil!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a bijective homomorphism.

We have 
$$
L_A(x + y) = A (x + y) = Ax + Ay = L_A(x) + L_A(y)
$$
so it is a homomorphism.

An invertible matrix satisfies
$$
A A^{-1} = A^{-1} A = I
$$
we have
$$
x 
= A A^{-1} x 
= L_A(A^{-1}x) 
= L_A(L_{A^{-1}}(x))
$$
or
$$
L_A \circ L_{A^{-1}} = \text{id}
$$
and similar
$$
L_{A^{-1}} \circ L_A = \text{id}
$$